# чем отличается вызов sizeof(переменная) от sizeof(struct)?

Tags: c

Собственно на данный вопрос натолкнул следующий вопрос:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); //так всё работает
//но если
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(addrinfo)); //то почему то возникают проблемы
```

вот не пойму теперь разве переменная типа А может занимать в памяти больше(меньше) чем размер этого типа?
Пример:

```
struct aaa
{
...
};

struct aaa var;
sizeof(aaa)!=sizeof(var)//можеь ли такое быть? и с чем это связано
```

И в каких случаях мы должны вычислять именно размер САМОЙ переменной в памяти, а не размер ТИПА переменной.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, всегда равны. Проблема в вопросе, на который Вы ссылаетесь, видимо в чем-то другом.

Comment: @avp вот почему то не происходит как я поняла корректного зануления структуры. Посмотрю в дебагере этот момент. А в чем разница всё-таки sizeof(тип) от sizeof(переменная).

Comment: Вообще-то, если у Вас Си (а не С++), то надо писать `sizeof(struct addrinfo)` (иначе просто не компилируется). Если у Вас Си и комплируется  `sizeof(addrinfo)`, то это означает, что есть *переменная* с таким именем и именно ее размер Вы смотрите. Может из-за этого и ошибки в "занулении". / А практической разницы между `sizeof(тип)` и `sizeof(переменная)` на мой взгляд нет.

Comment: Что касается собственно вопроса -- "в каких случаях мы должны вычислять именно размер САМОЙ переменной в памяти, а не размер ТИПА переменной" -- в большинстве случаев использовать `sizeof(TYPE)` не стоит, только для проверок, что какая-то переменная(ые) имеет нужный размер (например при работе с памятью переменной одного типа, как если бы она была другого типа).

Comment: @avp, вроде есть с массивами

Comment: @Grundy, если правильно записать тип массива, то то же самое -- `int a[10]; puts(sizeof(a) == sizeof(int[10]) ? "EQ" : "NE");`

Comment: @avp, ага, похоже

Answer (score 2):

> разве переменная типа А может занимать в памяти больше(меньше) чем размер этого типа?

Нет, не может.

> в каких случаях мы должны вычислять именно размер САМОЙ переменной в памяти, а не размер ТИПА переменной.

Например, в таких:

```
#define N 100
struct a { /* ... */ };

/* ... */

struct a aa[N];
size_t i;
for( i = 0; i < sizeof(aa)/sizeof(aa[0]); i++ {
 /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Хотите сказать, что тут м.б. `(sizeof(struct a) * N) != sizeof(aa)`?

Comment: @avp, не хочу. Но использование переменной вместо структуры кажется куда более логичным, естественным и понятным. Поэтому можно сказать, что в данном случае *следует* делать так. Но можно и не делать. Если скилл убегания от люлей прокачан. :-)

Comment: Ну, я в комментарии тоже написал примерно так (с точностью до инверсии) -- **практически всегда** надо использовать `sizeof(var_name)`